# MySQL synchronization between 2 databases

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a desktop Application which needs to be on an online database to sync between different devices. The problem is that the connection with the server 'in my case I use JawsDB free plan on Heroku' is very slow and takes a lot of time to load the initial data.

What I thought to do is to make an offline replica of the database and sync it from time to time when the user wants to sync with the online data. I did some research and I think using master-slave servers is the solution I'm looking for but for most of what I found the master was the online database.
I don't know much about databases but I think the master in my case is the Offline Database.

I'll appreciate if someone can tell me if it's the right solution for my problem and how to start implementing it (I'll be thankful if you can tell me how to implement a sync job that runs from code 'I'm using C#') or of course if there's another solution that should be implemented in my case.

Comment: This is too broad and opinionated for Stack Overflow, specially since synchronization is one of the most difficult tasks in the industry. I would say, avoid the need to synchronize unless it's completely necessary

Comment: Is the master-slave solution not appropriate in my case? I know that synchronization is difficult, that's why I need help to come up with a solution easier than tracking the differences.
I've seen few similar topics on stack overflow that's why I thought to ask here, I hope my question is not in the appropriate place.
@CamiloTerevinto